# How to refresh data after returning to a screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following cart screen which contains the address fields. When a user wants to update their address, they click on Update button, which takes them to the address screen where they can update the address. Although when the back button is clicked to return back to the cart screen,the print function shows the updated value but the UI still shows the old value.

```
 class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/cart';

  @override
  _CartScreenState createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
   Future _addressFuture;
   String value = 'deliver';
    var address;

  void initState() {
    _addressFuture = _obtainAddressFuture();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future _obtainAddressFuture() async {
    address = await Provider.of<Addresses>(context, listen: false).fetchMyAddress();
  }

  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    print('inside didchange'); 
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Rebuild cart'); 
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Your Cart'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder(
                future: _addressFuture,
                builder: (ctx, dataSnapshot) {
                  if (dataSnapshot.error != null) {
                    print('Data snapshot error is ' +
                        dataSnapshot.error.toString());
                    return Center(
                      child: Text('Something went wrong!'),
                    );
                  } else if (dataSnapshot.connectionState ==
                      ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Loading(),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Column(
                      children: [
                          Card(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 15,
                                vertical: 4,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [
                                      new GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () async{
                                        _awaitReturnValueFromSecondScreen(context);
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            child: const Text("Update",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.blue))),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),                                                  
                                 
                                  TextFormField(
                                    initialValue: address.name,
                                    readOnly: true,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person,
                                            color: Colors.orangeAccent),
                                        labelText: 'Contact name'),
                                    ),
                                ],
                              )),
                      ],
                    )));
                  }
                })));              
  }
   void _awaitReturnValueFromSecondScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    // start the SecondScreen and wait for it to finish with a result
    final result = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => AddressScreen('cartScreen'),
        ));
    setState(() {
      address = result;
    });

    print(address.name); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the below example as it requires `async` and `await` to get the data from 2nd screen

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Location',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
          ),
          home: Provider(
            create: (context) => Addresses(),
            child: CartScreen(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      static const routeName = '/cart';

      @override
      _CartScreenState createState() => _CartScreenState();
    }

    class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
      Future? _addressFuture;
      String value = 'deliver';
      var address;

      void initState() {
        _addressFuture = _obtainAddressFuture();
        super.initState();
      }

      Future _obtainAddressFuture() async {
        address =
            await Provider.of<Addresses>(context, listen: false).fetchMyAddress();
      }

      void didChangeDependencies() async {
        super.didChangeDependencies();
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Your Cart'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder(
              future: _addressFuture,
              builder: (ctx, dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.error != null) {
                  print('Data snapshot error is ' + dataSnapshot.error.toString());
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text('Something went wrong!'),
                  );
                } else if (dataSnapshot.connectionState ==
                    ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 15,
                            vertical: 4,
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: [
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      // Here you have to wait for the screen to retrun data so we use asyn await
                                      final result = await Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (_) =>
                                              AddressScreen(title: 'cartScreen'),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                      print(result);
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      child: const Text(
                                        "Update",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                // initialValue: address.name,
                                readOnly: true,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person,
                                      color: Colors.orangeAccent),
                                  labelText: 'Contact name',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class AddressScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const AddressScreen({
        Key? key,
        required this.title,
      }) : super(key: key);

      final String title;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Here you have pass the data that you want
                Navigator.pop(context, 'Data pass here ');
              },
              child: Text('Pass data back'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class Addresses {
      Future fetchMyAddress() async {}
    }
```

Comment: So then how do you set the name value? I see that you have commented out the initValue attribute of the name textformfield. Note that when the cartscreen loads for the first time, the address data is fetched from database via fetchMyAddress function. And then when the user navigates to addressscreen and back to cart, the address needs to be updated.

Comment: Do you want to update the name? then use set state when your return from the Address screen

Comment: Please show it in your example.

Comment: Update the result value to textfield

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Comment: after following the example in the link you provided, I am able to print the value in the first screen but the UI still shows the old value.